# combined group by query on a large table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to query a large table something like 70 million records. The hard thing is that the group by query based on three fields does not respond. Is there a clever way of doing that? Is use of `VID` in group by section better rather than verb field?

This is the query I run :

```
SELECT 
    VID, s_name, verb, o_name, count(*) as total
FROM
table_name 
group by verb, s_name, o_name;
```

Comment: How many rows does you expect i.e what are you expecting from `count(*)`?

Comment: Can you `DESCRIBE` the table structure? I would expect e.g. the presence of indexes for the grouped fields to make a huge difference.

Comment: with count(*) I wanna get the number of rows for each group block.

Comment: Can you tell please, what is VID?

Comment: It is an integer field that corresponds to the verb field.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.  Doing aggregations in MySQL on 70 million rows is an expensive operation.

Can you try the following to see if performance is better?

```
create index idx_table_name_3 on table_name(s_name, verb, o_name);

select distinct s_name, verb, o_name
from table_name;
```

If this finishes in a finite amount of time, it might be possible to do the aggregation more efficiently.

Then try this:

```
select s_name, verb, o_name,
       (select count(*)
        from table_name t2
        where t2.s_name = t.s_name and
              t2.verb = t.verb and
              t2.o_name = t.o_name
       ) as cnt
from (select distinct s_name, verb, o_name
      from table_name
     ) t;
```

The subquery should be materialized using the index.  The aggregation should be calculated from the index as well.  If so, then this will trick MySQL into not using file sort for the `group by` -- and the performance may improve.

Comment: there is already a combined index element for those three fields.